# Cant cancel Axios post request via CancelToken

Tags: javascript, axios

This code cancel GET requests but cant abort POST calls.
If i send GET requests first and i dont cancel them via `abortAll` method,they just finish by themselves this token cancel by itself and doesnt work on next requests?
What am i missing?
Thanks,John

```
import axios from 'axios'
class RequestHandler {

 constructor(){
  this.cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  this.source = this.cancelToken.source();
 }

 get(url,callback){

  axios.get(url,{
   cancelToken:this.source.token,
  }).then(function(response){

        callback(response.data);

    }).catch(function(err){

        console.log(err);

    })

 }

post(url,callbackOnSuccess,callbackOnFail){
 axios.post(url,{

        cancelToken:this.source.token,

    }).then(function(response){

        callbackOnSuccess(response.data);

    }).catch(function(err){

        callbackOnFail()

    })
}

abortAll(){

 this.source.cancel();
    // regenerate cancelToken
 this.source = this.cancelToken.source();

}

}
```

Comment: pass the config object as the third param `axios.post(url, {}, {cancelToken:this.source.token})`

Comment: @wdm https://github.com/axios/axios says the post method takes two parameters - I don't think your suggestion will work

Comment: @SimonD Look under https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation for `axios.post('/user/12345', {name: 'new name'}, {cancelToken: source.token})`

Comment: @wdm ahah I see that now... https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/core/Axios.js has the extra data parameter. thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have found out that you can cancel post request this way,i missunderstand [this documentation part](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#cancellation).
In previous code,i have passed cancelToken to the POST data request not as a axios setting.

```
import axios from 'axios'


var CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
var cancel;

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/test',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  },
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
      // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
      cancel = c;
    })
}).then(()=>console.log('success')).catch(function(err){

  if(axios.isCancel(err)){

    console.log('im canceled');

  }
  else{

    console.log('im server response error');

  }

});
// this cancel the request
cancel()
```

Comment: Hello, I've searched for an example of axios cancelation.. however when I use this code, the browser crashes, giving me a devtools was disconnected error..

Comment: Can you provide your code and error message?Try on different browser.

Answer (score 15):

**Cancel previous Axios request on new request with cancelToken and source.**

https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

```
 // cancelToken and source declaration
  
 const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
 let source = CancelToken.source();

 source && source.cancel('Operation canceled due to new request.');
 
 // save the new request for cancellation
 source = axios.CancelToken.source();

 axios.post(url, postData, {
     cancelToken: source.token
 })
 .then((response)=>{
     return response && response.data;
 })
 .catch((error)=>{
     return error;
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

Using inside componentDidMount lifecycle hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source() // <-- 1st step

const fetchPost = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await Axios.get(`endpointURL`, {
      cancelToken: ourRequest.token, // <-- 2nd step
    })
    } catch (err) {
    console.log('There was a problem or request was cancelled.')
  }
}
fetchPost()

return () => {
  ourRequest.cancel() // <-- 3rd step
}
}, [])
```

Note: For POST request, pass cancelToken as 3rd argument

```
Axios.post(`endpointURL`, {data}, {
 cancelToken: ourRequest.token, // 2nd step
})
```

Comment: How would you got about doing it outside of a useEffect() hook? I'm having an issue where, when I have a function getting called inside the useEffect hook it cancels properly, but when I use that same function when a button is clicked my request does not cancel.

Comment: @justanotherguy as far as my understanding, we have to listen for events/side-effects continuously, so only way react gives us to listen to changes is via useEffect hook only. If you can share some snippet for your scenario then it would be better to find a solution.

Comment: I actually posted a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940054/cancel-axios-request-in-useeffect-not-running/61941923?noredirect=1#comment109559878_61941923 . If you have something else to add to it, please do. But what I ended up doing was use the useRef hook.

Comment: oh nice, you got the solution.

Comment: "Axios.post(`endpointURL`, {data}, {
 cancelToken: ourRequest.token, // 2nd step
})". That's is my mistake. It works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm wrong, but each request should have a unique source object.

Answer (score 1):

**Simplest implementation using ReactJs**

```
import axios from 'axios';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.axiosCancelSource = axios.CancelToken.source()

    axios
      .get('data.json', { cancelToken: this.axiosCancelSource.token })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          data: response.data.posts
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    console.log('unmount component')
    this.axiosCancelSource.cancel('Component unmounted.')
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state

    return (
     <div>
          {data.items.map((item, i) => {
            return <div>{item.name}</div>
          })}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```