# Handling axios cancel in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have the following scenario

```
const config = {
    timeout: 30000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: ``
    },
    cancelToken: cancelSource.token
};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let itr = 0;
    axios
        .post("/my/url", "", config)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status === 200) {
                if (i === itr) {
                    //set state here
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            if (axios.isCancel) {
                // How to know if the cancel stops already?
            }
        });
}
```

For example:
I have 16 items and 8 items were cancelled. How do I know if the cancel is done?
So I can set some post processing here.

Comment: Won’t the cancel be done right when the catch statement receives an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

axios.isCancel is a function which expects error as a param. But you are calling it as a key. So

Change

```
  .catch(error =>{
      if(axios.isCancel){
          // How to know if the cancel stops already?
     }
  });
```

To

```
  .catch(error =>{
      if(axios.isCancel(error)){
          // How to know if the cancel stops already?
      }
   });
```

with the above change you can be able to identify when the request is canceled.  You can simply play with local variable to manage the data received until it was cancelled. The reason you need to use local variable here because setState isn’t allowed inside loop. So push all the data into array and finally assign that array to a component state outside the loop

Comment: so in my cancel i'll just do something like cancelSource.cancel(someState) ?

Comment: You need to pass error which you get in catch block. I updated code in my answer you can check

Comment: .catch(error => {
                if(axios.isCancel(error)){
                    console.log(error);
                }

i tried that one but the error is undefined

Comment: Check this thread accepted answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852054/cant-cancel-axios-post-request-via-canceltoken