# How to make an async call after using axios.CancelToken?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, axios

I'm building a `React Native` app. My API component contains an async call which I want to be able to stop. For that purpose, I use `axios.CancelToken`:.

```js
const source = axios.CancelToken.source();


 async getProductCategoriesRequest() {
    try {
      let response = await catalog.get(`category`, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.reject();
      } 
    }
  }
```

From my component, I call `requestCancellationHandler` on `onPress`:

```js
 const requestCancellationHandler = () => {
    source.cancel('API request is being canceled');
    props.resetState();
  };
```

Everything works just fine except I cannot make another call unless I reload the app. I keep receiving `Cancel {message: "API request is being canceled"}` in API request Catch. Simple page reload allows me to make another async call

**How could I resolve that issue without having to reload?**

Comment: You're asking to cancel cancelling an axios request. You can't do that. Just make a new request.

Comment: No, the problem is that I cannot make another request after canceling.
It only allows me to send another request after I have restarted the app.

Comment: How are you calling `getProductCategoriesRequest`?

Comment: It looks like you might have to create a new CancelToken, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852054/cant-cancel-axios-post-request-via-canceltoken). You could change to `let source`, and set `source = axios.CancelToken.source()` before every request, inside `getProductCategoriesRequest`.

Comment: Sorry. I call it from my reducer  ```export const getCatalog = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
  ...
  let productCategoriesData = await catalogAPI.getProductCategoriesRequest();
  ...
}```

Comment: Wow. It worked. Thank you very much, I appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the second example in the [Axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation) would be useful.

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
let cancel;

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: new CancelToken(function executor(c) {
    // An executor function receives a cancel function as a parameter
    cancel = c;
  })
});

// cancel the request
cancel();
```

**In your case,**

```
let source;

 async getProductCategoriesRequest() {
    source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    try {
      let response = await catalog.get(`category`, {
        cancelToken: source.token,
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        console.log(error)
        return Promise.reject();
      } 
    }
  }
```

and

```
 const requestCancellationHandler = () => {
    source.cancel('API request is being canceled');
    props.resetState();
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the question, I don't use Axios much and I learnt something. And I don't know why someone downvoted without explaining.