# Cancel Axios request in useEffect not running

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

I am attempting to cancel an axios request, but I am only having partial success. I have this function that returns a Promise when I make a GET request:

```
const getCards = (token) => {
  const URL = isDev
    ? "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://privacy.com/api/v1/card"
    : "https://privacy.com/api/v1/card";
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    cancelToken: source.token,
  };

  return axios.get(URL, config);
};
```

I call this function inside `updateCards()` which looks like this:

```
const updateCards = async () => {
  console.log("Updating Cards");

  setCards([]);
  setStarted(true);
  setLoading(true);

  let response = await getCards(token).catch((thrown) => {
    if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
      console.error("[UpdateCards]", thrown.message);
    }
  });

  /**
   * response is undefined when we cancel the request on unmount
   */

  if (typeof response === "undefined") return console.log("Undefined");

  console.log("Got Response from UpdateCards", response);

  setLoading(false);
};
```

I cancel my request in the useEffect hook as so:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        source.cancel()
    }
}, [])
```

And I have setup my CancelToken under my state declaration like this:

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();
```

My issue is that, if I call my updateCards() function inside of the useEffect(), I can cancel it just fine, but if I use a button to call that same function the cancel is not ran. I have looked everywhere and the only solution I have found is that I have to call my requests within the useEffect() hook, but that is not something I want to do.Where do I go from here?

Here are the resources I have looked at:

https://github.com/axios/axios#cancellation

https://medium.com/@selvaganesh93/how-to-clean-up-subscriptions-in-react-components-using-abortcontroller-72335f19b6f7

[Cant cancel Axios post request via CancelToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44852054/cant-cancel-axios-post-request-via-canceltoken/61588551#61588551)

Comment: Why don't you want to use `useEffect` for updating cards?

Comment: Because the user could at anytime make another request which is not necessarily when  the component mounts. Also I would like to learn why the cancel is not running.

Comment: The `source` inside your `useEffect` is not going to be the same `source` that initiated the request; the code is likely canceling a different call than you expect. Can you paste the code where `source` is instantiated? Your issue sounds similar to [Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing myself, but couldn't figure out why it would be different. Here is where I am setting up my source. Let me upload it to hastebin.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/axemapahek.js @RossAllen Here is where my `source` is setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have a place to store a variable that behaves like an [instance variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) of the component, you can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). It's a container for anything you want. You can store the CancelToken in there:

```js
function Privacy(props) {
  const source = useRef(null);

  function getSource() {
    if (source.current == null) {
      const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      source.current = CancelToken.source();
    }
    return source.current;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (source.current != null) source.current.cancel();
    }
  }, [])

  // call `getSource()` wherever you need the Axios source
}
```

Comment: interesting, I'll take a look at the useRef hook and update the post if that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Just tested it and everything works great, thanks for the help. I ended up doing what you said, by using getSource() to set the cancelToken when making the GET request and then and using the source.current to cancel the requests on unmount.

Comment: Great, glad it worked. `useRef` can enable some powerful Hooks. That chunk of code you could easily pull into a new custom hook called `useSource` or something similar, and it would return `source.current`.